# Change statusbar tint colour

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

Is there a way to set the status bar tint colour?
I have my navigationbar tint set to brown and when it's on screen it also changes the statusbar to brown, however on views that I hide the navigationbar the statusbar returns to its original colour.
How can I change the statusbar tint colour to persist trough the application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way in iOS 5. You can just change your bar style.

But if you take a look at new WWDC 2012 Sessions, you may find something interesting)

Session number 216 - Advanced Appearance Customization on iOS

Comment: Thanks I'll check that out. I'm using iOS6 so that could be why it's changing colour with the nav bar. I wish it didn't now as I'll have to do 2 seperate things for 5 & 6.

Comment: There is a way to make it stay the same, whatch that session - the second part, as far as i remember.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe keep the notification bar there but cover it up? If the notification bar's color influences that of the status bar, then it would lead me to believe that it just has to be in the window (even buried under another view) to change it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way in iOS 5 or ealier version of ios.

now ios 6 have feature to change status bar tint color or it will set according to navigation bar pattern Image

But u can use [Custom Status Bar](https://github.com/myell0w/MTStatusBarOverlay)

Comment: NDA, we can't talk about it so loud)

Comment: I am actually using the latest [redacted] *cough cough* so that could be why it changes colour with the nav bar. I can't find a status bar tint setting though.

Answer (score 0):

What I do in screens that have no navigation bar is to put in a navigation bar at the top but *behind* the visible interface. The navigation bar is not visible to the user, but it is visible to the system and causes the status bar to adopt its color.

EDIT: Sorry, I see now that someone else had already suggested this. So I'm just confirming that it does work.

Comment: What method do you use to hide it? Can you just send it to back?

Comment: @Darren Yep. It must be at the top of the view, but it can be behind everything else.