# IOS status bar not translucent

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, statusbar

I have a navigation view controller. The root view hides the navigation bar using `self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true`.

No matter what I do I cannot get the`statusBar` to be translucent it is simply a white block that pushes my content below.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't get a translucent status bar in iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568896/cant-get-a-translucent-status-bar-in-ios)

Comment: the above suggests self.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES; which is depreciated.

Comment: You want translucent or LightContent status bar? I can't find the translucent option in Xcode

Comment: *it is simply a white block that pushes my content below.* so you want to hide the status bar completely? Please be as clear and specific as possible. Add a picture to your question of the desired outcome if possible.

Comment: @Ben_hawk Did you manage to fix the issue? If yes, please post the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can make status bar translucent as -

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent];
```

// set full screen layout  in view controller class

```
self.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
```

Comment: wantsFullScreenLayout is depreciated

Comment: above iOS 7.0 you need to use --(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle{ 
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent; 
}

Comment: still the same result

Comment: I believe this is something that could be related to that fact that this is the root view controller for the navigation and has the navigation navbar hidden.

Comment: are you using any school view/ table view on your view controller?

Comment: Nope just a standard view controller as the root view